# Fazer um select de acordo com uma tabela indexada

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, stored-procedures

Eu tenho uma tabela, *getSalas*, que simplificada é algo assim:

```
CREATE TABLE getSalas(
    ID_SALA NUMBER(4),
    NOME_CARATERISTICA VARCHAR2(20),
    VALOR_CARATERISTICA NUMBER(4)
);
```

Os conteúdos desta tabela são do tipo:

> 1, 'Extintor', 2
>
> 1, 'A/C', 1
>
> 2, 'A/C', 2

O que no contexto do meu problema significa que o quarto com o *ID* 1 tem 2 extintores e 1 Ar-condicionado, e o quarto com o *ID* tem 2 Ar-condicionados.
Também criei uma tabela indexada de um tipo de dados que eu criei:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE c_valor FORCE IS OBJECT (CARATERISTICA VARCHAR2(20), VALOR NUMBER(30));
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tabc_valor FORCE IS TABLE OF c_valor;
/
```

O que eu preciso saber é se, **por exemplo**, um quarto tem pelo menos um ar-condicionado e um extintor, para isso eu criei o seguinte procedimento:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getSalas_Carateristicas
(v_carateristicas IN tabc_valor, lista OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS BEGIN
    OPEN lista FOR SELECT getSalas.ID_SALA
    FROM getSalas, TABLE(v_carateristicas) v_carateristicas
    WHERE getSalas.NOME_CARATERISTICA = v_carateristicas.CARATERISTICA
    AND getSalas.VALOR >= v_carateristicas.VALOR
    GROUP BY getSalas.ID_SALA
    ORDER BY getSalas.ID_SALA;
END;
/
```

E em *v_carateristicas* eu tenho os valores, neste caso seria algo do tipo

> 'A/C', 1
>
> 'Extintor', 1

O problema deste procedimento é que ele retorna a sala com o *ID* 1 e a sala com o *ID* 2, porque ele está a fazer um **OU**, isto é, se a sala tiver A/C ou um extintor retorna esta sala também, mas eu queria que ele fizesse um **E**, se a sala tiver A/C e um extintor retorna esta sala também.

### Nota 1:

Eu criei um procedimento, porque está pesquisa é dinâmica, isto é, agora eu quero uma sala com A/C e um extintor, depois vou querer uma sala com 2 unicórnios e a seguir uma sala com 3 unicórnios, piscina e A/C.
Com dinheiro tudo é possível ;)

### Nota 2:

O parâmetro de entrada do procedimento, *v_carateristicas*, é uma tabela indexada com a seguinte estrutura:

> Nome da carateristica, valor
>
> Nome da carateristica, valor
>
> Nome da carateristica, valor etc...

Caso eu queira uma sala com 2 unicórnios e uma piscina o *v_carateristicas* será:

> 'Unicórnio', 2
>
> 'Piscina', 2

### Nota 2:

Se possível gostaria de encontrar uma solução que mexesse apenas com o procedimento, seria um pouco complicado voltar a mexer com as tabelas, contudo apresentem as vossas sugestões sejam elas quais forem!

Comment: Removi a minha resposta por não atender o seu problema da forma como você quer. Vou pensar numa solução assim que eu tiver um pouco mais de tempo. Pergunta interessante. `+1`

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda @MarllonNasser, volte quando quiser :)

Comment: Pelo que entendi eu faria de outra forma , montaria uma sql dinamica (cuidado com injection) com as condições a serem buscadas, me parece mais simples.

Comment: Me desculpe não entendi, @Motta

Answer (score 0):

Se quer buscar O ARRAY

```
 'A/C', 1
 'Extintor', 1
```

Monta-se a sql assim

```
DECLARE 
   vs_sql varchar2(4000):
 Begin
   --SUPONDO UM ARRAY   
   vs_sql :=           'SELECT getSalas.ID_SALA';
   vs_sql := vs_sql || 'FROM getSalas WHERE 1=1';
   FOR I IN -- LOOP DO ARRAY
   LOOP
     vs_sql := vs_sql || 'and getSalas.NOME_CARATERISTICA =' || ARRAY(I,1);
     vs_sql := vs_sql || 'AND getSalas.VALOR >=' || ARRAY(I,2) ;
   END LOOP;
   open cursor for vs_sql;
 End;
```

Apenas um rascunho da ideia